# Medium applications for api access no longer available to free users?

Tags: medium.com-publishing-api

I've created a medium application for API access a while ago, and I've been using it to connect medium accounts to my website and let them publish stories from my website. But it stopped working recently, and I can't access my app anywhere. I should mention that my medium account isn't premium, so I've been thinking that's the problem. The thing is I can't find any info anywhere about medium preventing free users from creating apps. This is where I've managed my apps in the past: [Link](https://medium.com/me/applications), but now I get 403. Does anyone have any info about this?

edit: What I forgot to say is, when I try to connect my account, I receive the access/refresh token, but then when I try the "https://api.medium.com/v1/me" endpoint I get

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Application not found",
            "code": 6005
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm a free user who was using the api and it is failing me in the last days....

Comment: @fernand0 What's interesting is that they haven't said anything anywhere, and they ignore me on both twitter and medium.

Comment: I asked a question in medium support system and they restored the token, not sure what to think about this.

Comment: Still haven't answered me.. Can you access https://medium.com/me/applications?

Comment: Yes, I can, and I also can see it in settings, in the integrations section.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, guess I'll ask them again.

Comment: Good luck. It's a nice feature.

Comment: It's because of Medium need to reduce spam from API so they require the following elements to identify your user. 

A profile name,
A bio,
An avatar,
Two samples of your writing published to Medium

Comment: How did you guys get the token? I have been emailing medium to get access to the token but am yet to hear back - its been more than a week. Have chased them couple times already too.

Comment: @S.Simkhada i wrote to yourfriends@medium.com and they responded within a couple of days.

Comment: @AlexV I finally got a reply few days ago after chasing for weeks. They said they are currently evaluating their api and are not giving out any new access tokens. Also said they have no time frame on when we can expect the tokens to be available.